# Laravel 5 generation carbon date time with timezone

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I have publish ERP site in cloud platform and I want to generate datetime for user assigned timezones.

I am using carbon datetime library to convert. But its gave me bellow issue when i am converting.

```
$carbon = new Carbon();
$carbon->setTimezone('Asia/colombo');
echo $carbon;           //output is  : 2016-07-06 22:33:05 | Asia/colombo
BUT
echo $carbon->now()     // output is : 2016-07-06 17:03:05 | UTC
```

> Why **$carbon->now** is giving wrong timezone even I have set timezone in carbon object also....

sorry If I am thinking wrong way.........

Answer (score 3):

`Carbon::now` is a static function, which you invoke on your object but it is *still* a static function. There is no underlying object to pull the timezone information from. You need to do this: `Carbon::now('Asia/colombo')`

Comment: That's mean i should pass the timezone for all the functions.

Comment: No, you can use `$carbon->toDateTimeString()` like shock_gone_wild mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Carbon's setTimezone() function on an object, you should only call non static functions on that object.

After manually applying a timezone, just use the non static output functions.

Some examples:

```
// without parameters it is now() !
$carbon = new Carbon\Carbon();
$carbon->setTimezone('Asia/colombo');
echo $carbon->toDateTimeString()."<br>";
// custom output format
echo $carbon->format('d.m.Y H:i:s')."<br>";

$carbon->setTimezone('Europe/Berlin');
echo $carbon->toDateTimeString()."<br>";
// custom output format
echo $carbon->format('d.m.Y H:i:s')."<br>";


// or pass something compatible to http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
$carbon = new Carbon\Carbon('24.12.2015 20:13');
$carbon->setTimezone('Asia/colombo');
echo $carbon->toDateTimeString()."<br>";
// custom output format
echo $carbon->format('d.m.Y H:i:s')."<br>";

$carbon->setTimezone('Europe/Berlin');
echo $carbon->toDateTimeString()."<br>";
// custom output format
echo $carbon->format('d.m.Y H:i:s')."<br>";
```

The static methods will use the timezone defined in your config/app.php  ( default: UTC)

Comment: Is this ok may i use date_default_timezone_set($timeZone->name);

Comment: I would not call date_default_timezone_set()...   And also I wouldn't change Laravel's global timezone to match current users timezone... Just store all the dates that are required by your application in the same format and convert them on output to users timezone...

Comment: Thanks & seems it's a pretty cool idea. I also notice that changing laraval global timezone is not a good idea.